# Not able to reference the Test with a Datapool in IBM Mobilefirst Platform Test Workbench 8.7(Free Version)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-mtw

**Tool Used:** IBM Mobilefirst Platform Test Workbench 8.7 (Free Version) 
**OS:** Windows 7

**Problem Description:**
1) Have created a Test case in Test Workbench in Record mode. (For a Login Scenario)
2) Inserted a new Datapool and have added values to Username column in the Datapool.
3) The Test script must refer the datapool and substitute the values from Datapool Username column into the Username field in the Test script.
4) Have followed the procedure outlined here. 
 (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2HS7_8.7.0/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.moeb.tutorial.doc/topics/ios_lesson7.html) 
5) Getting stuck in Step **6.b**. I right click on Username field in test script and select **Substitute** and get an option **Select Data Source** 
6) The **Select Data Source** option is disabled.

Is this because i am using a free version and not a licensed version of IBM Mobilefirst Platform Test Workbench 8.7 ?

Comment: There are no license restrictions for MTW. What is your MFP version?

Comment: MFP Version is  6.3.0

Comment: MTW 7.0 is not supported in MFP 6.3. Only in MFP 7.0 and above. Please downgrade and check again.

Comment: Using MTW 8.7 and MFP 7.0. Have taken below screenshots for clearer presentation of problem. Please download from google drive.    1) https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_oG-jJKHvh4OHU2WUkzWkVvVmdlMmk2RzNKSXcxTWd4MjhB/edit?usp=docslist_api                                2)https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_oG-jJKHvh4aUZxSlhVUl9WVG8/edit?usp=docslist_api

Comment: @Idan Adar: Any suggestions on how i go about this or is this a limitation with IBM Mobilefirst Platform Test Workbench 8.7 ? Hope the problem presentation was clear.

Comment: You could perhaps pursue help by opening a PMR