# Select Data Source is disabled under Substitute when try to add a data pool to project in IBM Mobilefirst Platform Test Workbench 8.7

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-mtw

Select Data Source is disabled under Substitute when try to add a data pool to project in IBM Mobilefirst Platform Test Workbench 8.7. [I am having the same issue mentioned by @Rakesh Manusani in his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024641/not-able-to-reference-the-test-with-a-datapool-in-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-test).

1. I Have followed the steps mentioned in below link.
   (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2HS7_8.7.0/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.moeb.tutorial.doc/topics/ios_lesson7.html)
2. I was able to select the data pool to use in test

I am stuck in Step 6.b.

I right click on Username field in test script and select Substitute and get an option Select Data Source but it looks disabled

I am using MTW 8.7 and MFP 7.0

Comment: If you are having the same issue in another question - why did you open a new question? Duplicate.

Comment: Hi @IdanAdar Thanks for your concern. Since that question did not have an answer I had to raise a new question. Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks-Prabu

Comment: Looks like you've already answered the other question on this same topic - please either copy your answer to here as well or remove this question.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of: [Not able to reference the Test with a Datapool in IBM Mobilefirst Platform Test Workbench 8.7(Free Version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024641/not-able-to-reference-the-test-with-a-datapool-in-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-test/)

> **Steps to follow**:
>
> 1. Create the project  and record the test
> 2. Create the data pool with variable(s) and Value(s) as per req.
> 3. If you want to substitute the value of data table in you script
> 4. Say if the username is stored under the variable "User" in data pool.
> 5. Then at the script property on the right side, where you input username, replace the recorded value with the variable name "User"
> 6. Now **double click** on the text in the username text field ("User"), means all the text value in the Username field in test
>      script should be highlighted, like Ctrl+A.
> 7. IF do a right click now on the highlighted text you will find **Select Data Source** option enabled under **Substitute**